# Permutations but with some numbers kept in an order

Tags: python, c, algorithm, sorting, permutation

Ok, I have had a browse around and I have looking for either a C or python solution to this problem. I would prefer python...although it is my weaker language (of 2 very weak languages).

A set of numbers, such as 0 0 1 7 0 0 3 0 0 4

1. Find all permutations of the set.
2. The numbers >0 must stay in that order (NOT POSITION!)
3. There MUST be a 0 between numbers, a 0 is not required at the start and end of the set though. As long as there is AT LEAST ONE 0 between numbers >0.

So firstly, I thought of just finding all possible permutations and then removing the chaff (checking that if n>0 , !n+1>0) for each permutation and then the first number >0 == 1, 2nd # >0 ==7 etc. etc.

I then stopped and thought that was daft, say there were 12 numbers, that would give 12! permutations. This in the order of 500,000,000 permutations of which I would have to run through again to get rid of chaff.

Say I had 40-50 sets of these number sets to go through, that is a fair whack of time.

Is there a more logical way?
I thought of somehow having python do permutations somehow taking those rules in to account (if n>0, n+1 MUST == 0) and (n=first number, n2=2nd etc.)

An example of a smaller set would be (NOT ALL PERMUTATIONS, but gives idea):

**1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0**

1. 1,0,2,0,3,0,0,0
2. 0,1,0,2,0,3,0,0
3. 0,0,1,0,2,0,3,0
4. 0,0,1,0,0,2,0,3
5. 0,1,0,0,2,0,3,0

etc. etc.
So 1,2,3 is in order but the "0"s are just shifted about?

Thanks!

Comment: The second result of the smaller example seems to violate rule 3.

Comment: Oooops....rushed thinking. Fixing it now.

Comment: In the end, are you going to compare each one of these strings to some input, in order to validate that input?  If so, maybe research "edit distance" calculations instead of trying to brute-force every permutation.

Comment: @jez Thanks! I am looking that up now. Seems more of what I needed. Just did not know what it was called! Shift the space between and before/after the numbers.

Comment: If you do want to generate every permutation, it's actually a much smaller problem than `n!`. In your first example `1 0 7 0 3 0 4` is the inviolable core ordering, according to your three rules, into which you must now insert 3 extra zeros, placing them anywhere you like.  There are 8 positions for the first zero, 9 for the second, 10 for the third, so 720 possibilities.

Comment: @jez Adding a 0 before or after another 0 doesn't really give a unique sequence, though I suppose you could just filter them out in a later step.

Comment: Some comments: since the numbers stay in order you are left with just permuting on moving the excess zeros around right? So in your example 3 zeros are moved. Stack exchange is not here to do your homework for you. You indicate language by using tags. Read this: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html, it helps you ask better questions and avoid irritating the people who you want to help you with their free time.

Comment: Sorry, it is not homework. I am actually a science teacher and programming is my new hobby I am trying to learn. Sorry if I do not know the lores of StackOverflow.

Was told problems are the best way to go about it so found a problem and can not fathom the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you want to reduce the number of combinations you have to compute by grouping things according to their invariants.  Since the non-zero numbers must be in a fixed order let's start with that:

```
   1 2 3
```

Since there must be 0's between them add them in

```
   1 0 2 0 3
```

Now what you are left with is three 0's to place and you need to figure how many combinations give distinct sequences.  Clearly from this example the possible positions you have are: before the 1, between the 1 and 2, between the 2 and 3 and after the 3.  You have 4 positions in which to decide how to split up the remaining three 0's.  This is a [combination problem with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition), for which the solution here is `(3 + 4 - 1) Choose 3` (which is 20).

Hopefully the way that I went through this example problem is enough for you to generalize this to arbitrary sequences, so I will leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @Jcov That was fast, did you implement and test this already?

Comment: Yep, this is bang on what I want. It is like I want to share a number between x spaces, getting all permutations of that instead.

Ticked and upvoted thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, is the tick to say "I have done it" or to say "the best answer to the problem"? I am noob here :(.

Comment: @Jcov, I don't think it's a hard rule, but it is best to make sure that solved your problem first for a couple of reasons.  If there is a mistake in my work, people will be more likely to miss it because it's already marked correct.  Also, people are much less likely to answer a question with an accepted answer, so you're less likely to get better (or correct, if my answer has a mistake) answers, or other interesting input.

Comment: @Jcov, There's no harm in waiting for an answer, but at the same time if this answer does really solve your problem as well as you need and you don't really need more input (which may or may not come, if others answer or don't) then it's fine to mark it as correct right away and move on.

Comment: @Jcov, Again, these aren't rules, just my observations from questions I've seen go by and from ones I've asked myself.

Answer (score 3):

```
def find_permutations(l):
    n = [e for e in l if e] # Strip zeros.
    # Interspace non-zeros with zeros.
    m = [j for i in n for j in (i,0)][:-1]
    def fill(m):
        if len(m) == len(l):
            yield tuple(m)
        else:
            # Recursively fill with zeros.
            for i in range(len(m)+1):
                for o in fill(m[:i] + [0] + m[i:]):
                    yield tuple(o)
    return sorted(set(fill(m)))
```

I think this should cover it. So for instance (in python 3), you could do:

```
>>> [print(p) for p in find_permutations([1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0])]
(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0)
(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3)
(0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0)
(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3)
(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0)
(0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3)
(1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3)
(1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0)
(1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3)
(1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0)
(1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3)
(1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0)
(1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0)
```

Was this similar to what you had in mind?

**Edit:** basically what the function called `fill` does is insert a zero between each number of the list, and recurse. Whenever enough numbers are recorded in the `fill` function (list length of recursively generated numbers equals list length of original input) a tuple of numbers is returned.

The only reason for converting to tuples when returning is that the type must be hashable to use in a set, as seen on the last line of the `find_permutations` function. `sorted` is for niceness.

Comment: Whoa ummm yeah bang on.
Now I need to spend about a week knowing how on Earth that works! Thanks.
Even the stripping zeros has me lost.

Comment: Zero stripping is using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It's an extremely powerful language construct, which basically just rolls up your for loop in one line and returns a new list, functional style.